# Reading data from a process (game)

Tags: reverse-engineering

I want to read data from a game. In this case it's Rocket League (Basically football with cars).

This data can be:

- Current score
- Player names / Team names
- Game duration
- etc.

Reading thru the internet I found to approaches:

### Memory reading

I try to find the addresses of the variables in the memory the game is using. This could be done by using a low-level programming language such as C++ (?).

### Package sniffing

This is probably a bad idea, however since Rocket League is a multiplayer game, data is send over the internet. One could catch and analyze the packages, provided that the connection is not encrypted.

I know that is by far not an easy task. What are your advises?
Feel free to share good articles regarding this topic.

Comment: You can use tools like `ArtMoney` to find memory addresses quickly.

Comment: To read data from another process programing language does not matter. What matters is API of the platform. For example windows has `ReadProcessMemory` to read other processes memory. You can call it from different languages.
What is package sniffing? Did you mean network packets sniffing? When the traffic is encrypted you have to analyze the code of the game to find out where it is decrypted.
Reading memory and intercepting packets are easy tasks, the really difficult task is to interpret the read data - what different read bytes mean.